# Waiting for the Doctor algorithmn question

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Question:

There are n patients currently waiting to see the doctor. The ith patient requires an estimated consultation time of ti minutes, as determined by the triage. There is only one doctor, and the doctor can only serve a single patient at any point in time, and all other patients must wait. For example, if the ﬁrst patient that the doctor serves has ti = 5, the remaining n−1 patients must all wait for an additional 5 minutes. You may assume that once the doctor ﬁnishes serving a patient, he will immediately serve the next patient — any time in between serving two patients is negligible. The doctor can serve the patients in any order. The doctor must serve all patients. The doctor wishes to minimize the total waiting time of all patients. **Describe the most eﬃcient algorithm you can think of to ﬁnd the minimum total waiting time required to serve all patients. What is the running time of your algorithm?**

In the suggested answer, a greedy approach is used.
All the patients are sorted by waiting time -- O(N log N).
Serve patients in increasing Ti -- O(N).
Total: O(N log N).

However, i was thinking that with the given constraints, to minimize the total waiting time will simply be serving the patient with the longest consultation last.
Thus i will make one pass through n patients to find patient P with the longest consultation time. Make a second pass to perform rolling sum in order to determine the total waiting time, and when i encounter the patient P, i will skip this patient. This will take O(n).

May i know what's wrong with this approach ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it would actually be O(n^2) because you'd have to search the entire list repeatedly for every single person. Or am I misreading this?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment! I am only searching the entire list once to find the maximum consultation time, so this takes linear time.Then i iterate through the entire list again, but perform a rolling sum which takes linear time as well. So i think it should be O(n) if i am not wrong!

Comment: Cross-posted to [Waiting for the Doctor@cs.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/129333/19966).

Comment: Please provide proper attribution and credit for the source of all copied text.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach minimizes the *longest* waiting time, not the *total* waiting time. It's not just the last patient who has to wait, all others have some waiting time as well (except the first) and you're ignoring that.

Answer (score -1):

Image 3 patients. One at 5 minutes, one at 20 minutes, one patient at 1 hour. If seen in ascending order, total patient wait time is 25 minutes. If seen in descending order, total time is 2 hours 20 minutes. So sort the list into ascending order. Now your question is "what is the most efficient sort". Any answer depends on how big the items, keys and number of items. Additional real world constraints: patient dies while waiting, more patients arrive during the 8 hour session, a patient offers to pay cash, double, and so on. Real triage also reorders the priorities. Next, what hardware / system / software is available? If JAVA, timsort. If Unix probably qsort. The only sort techniques that I am sure reasonably allows adding items are insertion sort and merge sort. If SQL create table, using the estimated time as the primary key / index. One can then causally add or delete patients/rows.

Comment: You talk a lot but didn't even *attempt* to answer the OP's question: What's wrong with their approach?